# Juniper SRX1400 VPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn, juniper, cisco-pix

I have been trying to set up a client VPN on a Juniper SRX1400 without much success. All documentation I found from Juniper and elsewhere does a lot of other (difficult and wonderful) things other than the simple things I want to do. We already have a VPN running on CISCO PIX hardware which we need to put to rest and we pretty much like to replicate the functionality, which is: 1) client makes a request to the outside interface of the SRX1400, 2) client gets authenticated, 3) if successful, then client is assigned all the usual DHCP stuff and becomes part of the network. What privileges this DHCP assigned network has, should be configurable of course with the usual routing/filtering methods.

Am I asking for too much from the SRX for this kind of thing? Should I ditch the SRX for VPN and revert to an OpenVPN solution that I had working some time back also and was amazed at the ease of configuration, functionality and features?

Answer (score 1):

the feature you are looking for is called **Dynamic VPN** in the Juniper World, the model you are refering to (SRX1400) is the first high end model on the datacenter level, they do no support Dynamic VPN.

never the less you can use **Shrew** a VPN client witch is free.

here is a sample configuration to use shrew on junos 10.4

```
## Last changed: 2011-01-17 21:14:39 MST
version 10.4R1.9;
system {
        login {
        user admin {
            uid 2002;
            class super-user;
        }
    }
    services {
        ssh;
        telnet;
        web-management {
            http;
        }
    }
    syslog {
        user * {
            any emergency;
        }
        file messages {
            any notice;
            authorization info;
        }
        file traffic-log {
            any any;
            match RT_FLOW;
        }
    }
}
interfaces {
    ge-0/0/0 {
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                address 10.4.4.1/24;
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/1 {
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                address 4.4.4.1/24;
            }
        }
    }
    fe-0/0/7 {
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                address 192.168.180.39/24;
            }
        }
    }
}
security {
    ike {
        proposal RemoteVPNPolicy1 {
            authentication-method pre-shared-keys;
            dh-group group2;
            authentication-algorithm md5;
            encryption-algorithm 3des-cbc;
            lifetime-seconds 86400;
        }
        policy RemoteVPNIKE {
            mode aggressive;
            proposals RemoteVPNPolicy1;
            pre-shared-key ascii-text "$9$ywMeMXVwgUjq7-jqmfn6revW7-"; # SECRET-DATA
        }
        policy t400-ike-policy {
            mode aggressive;
            proposals RemoteVPNPolicy1;
            pre-shared-key ascii-text "$9$IcPhyKX7V4aUM8aUjH5TRhSrM8"; # SECRET-DATA
        }
        inactive: gateway RemoteVPN {
            ike-policy RemoteVPNIKE;
            dynamic user-at-hostname "remote@domain.com";
            external-interface ge-0/0/1.0;
        }
        gateway t400-ike-gw {
            ike-policy t400-ike-policy;
            dynamic {
                user-at-hostname "remote@domain.com";
                connections-limit 50;
                ike-user-type shared-ike-id;
            }
            external-interface ge-0/0/1.0;
            xauth access-profile t400-access;
        }
    }
    ipsec {
        proposal RemoteVPNIPSec {
            protocol esp;
            authentication-algorithm hmac-md5-96;
            encryption-algorithm 3des-cbc;
        }
        policy RemoteVPNIPSec {
            proposals RemoteVPNIPSec;
        }
        policy t400-ipsec-policy {
            proposals RemoteVPNIPSec;
        }
        inactive: vpn RemoteVPN {
            ike {
                gateway RemoteVPN;
                ipsec-policy RemoteVPNIPSec;
            }
            establish-tunnels on-traffic;
        }
        vpn t400-vpn {
            ike {
                gateway t400-ike-gw;
                ipsec-policy t400-ipsec-policy;
            }
        }
    }
    zones {
        security-zone corp {
            interfaces {
                fe-0/0/7.0 {
                    host-inbound-traffic {
                        system-services {
                            all;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        security-zone trust {
            address-book {
                address hq-net-10-4-4 10.4.4.0/24;
            }
            interfaces {
                ge-0/0/0.0 {
                    host-inbound-traffic {
                        system-services {
                            all;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        security-zone untrust {
            interfaces {
                ge-0/0/1.0 {
                    host-inbound-traffic {
                        system-services {
                            all;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    policies {
        from-zone untrust to-zone trust {
            policy RemoteVPN {
                match {
                    source-address any;
                    destination-address hq-net-10-4-4;
                    application any;
                }
                then {
                    permit {
                        tunnel {
                            ipsec-vpn t400-vpn;
                        }
                    }
                    log {
                        session-init;
                        session-close;
                    }
                    count;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
access {
    address-pool t400-pool {
        address-range low 192.168.40.200 high 192.168.40.250 mask 55.255.255.0;
        primary-dns 10.4.4.75;
    }
    profile t400-access {
        authentication-order password;
        client joe {
            firewall-user {
                password "$9$K9QWX-YgJHqfVwqfTzCAvWLxVw"; ## SECRET-DATA
            }
        }
        address-assignment {
            pool t400-assign-pool;
        }
    }
    address-assignment {
        pool t400-assign-pool {
            family inet {
                network 192.168.40.0/24;
                range t400-range {
                    low 192.168.40.101;
                    high 192.168.40.149;
                }
                xauth-attributes {
                    primary-dns 10.4.4.85/32;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```